# what will be the advantages and features when i move Perl 5.8.8 to Perl 5.18.2(perl_5.18.2 Advantages)?

Tags: perl, version

What will be the advantages and features when i move  Perl 5.8.8 to Perl 5.18.2.

Notes:
1. i need advantages and disadvantages of perl 5.8.8
2. i need advantages and disadvantages of perl 5.18.2

Comment: If you exclude various bug fixes then, http://perldoc.perl.org/index-history.html

Answer (score 5):

You can read about the details in the [perldeltas](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-history.html). But apart from that

- perl 5.8.8 is old and no longer supported for years. There are enough modules which need a newer perl version.
- From 5.8.8 to 5.18.2 lots of nice language features where introduced.
- If you have non-trivial existing code it might break when you move from 5.8.8 to 5.18.2 because of all the changes.

Comment: While any responsible developer would read through the perl deltas, Highlights are available in `feature`: https://metacpan.org/pod/feature .  There are also significant improvements in RegEx Engine speed and Unicode handling